# Assigning each integer in for loop to input id attribute[for loop works fine]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I am trying to assign each integer of **for loop**, into id attribute of the input element.

I am expecting an output like this 
===>

```
<div style="clear:both">
<input class="dataFromSpreadsheet" type="text" style="float:left" id="0:0" value="">
<input class="dataFromSpreadsheet" type="text" style="float:left" id="0:1" value="">
<input class="dataFromSpreadsheet" type="text" style="float:left" id="0:2" value="">
</div>
```

However, my output is like this now ===>

```
<div style="clear:both">
<input class="dataFromSpreadsheet" type="text" style="float:left" id="7:2" value="">
<input class="dataFromSpreadsheet" type="text" style="float:left" id="7:2" value="">
<input class="dataFromSpreadsheet" type="text" style="float:left" id="7:2" value="">
</div>
```

```js
var newTable = "<input class = 'dataFromSpreadsheet' type = 'text' style = 'float:left' id = '' value = ''>";
for (var row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
  document.write("<div style = 'clear:both'>");
  console.log(row + 'this is row') // this works, starting from 0 to 7
  for (var col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
    $('.dataFromSpreadsheet').attr('id', row + ':' + col);
    document.write(newTable);
    console.log(col + 'this is column') // this works, starting from 0 to 2
  }
  document.write("</div>")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I do not understand why the output is **id = 7 : 2**, although both for loop works fine.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: your first loop executes till count is 7. but before executes inner loop, first loop completed its transaction because document.write takes some time. you should use recursive fn to solve that issue

Comment: @Satpal I am using `document.write` to create a new element on the document. Do you mean that I should be using other methods in jQuery, since I use jQuery in my code?

Comment: Note that you should not use numbers as the id - although it is now valid in HTML5 to use them - CSS selectors may not target elements as expected. You should use existing practises of prefixing with a name and dividing with either underscores or hyphens - eg: $('.dataFromSpreadsheet').attr('id', 'input_'+ row +'_'+col); or $('.dataFromSpreadsheet').attr('id', 'input-'+ row +'-'+col);  - this has the added benfit of being able to split on predictable characters to target elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling

`$('.dataFromSpreadsheet').attr('id', row +':'+col);` multiple times and what it does it overites the id for all  the inputs ,so you get 7:2 because that is when the loops stop overiding

You need to loop over each `.dataFromSpreadsheet` and add the id for a single item

try something like this:

```js
for (var row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
  document.write("<div style = 'clear:both'>");
  console.log(row + 'this is row') // this works, starting from 0 to 7
  for (var col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
  var newTable = "<input class = 'dataFromSpreadsheet' type = 'text' style = 'float:left' id = '"+ row + ':' + col+"' value = ''>";

    document.write(newTable);
    console.log(col + 'this is column') // this works, starting from 0 to 2
  }
  document.write("</div>")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked! I find a subtle difference between my code and yours. May I ask further about how your code works? Your code ==> `id = ' "+ row + ':' + col+" '`.  [Q1] Why do you need "" in this case?? In my case, my code was ===> `id = 'row + ':' + col'` (which did not work apparently)

Comment: your code was using `$('.dataFromSpreadsheet').attr('id', row +':'+col);`, the code looks for **all** elements on the page with the class `.dataFromSpreadsheet` and changes the id to the current combination in the loop, my code on tho other hand will build each element with a unique id because i moved newTable variabile inside the loops

Comment: Thank you for replying :) I see, I have another problem and tried to implement your advice. However, it did not work.`function populateSheet(result){
            for (var row = 0; row < 8; row++){
              for (var col = 0; col < 3; col++){
                var dataFromSpreadSheet = result.values[row][col];
                console.log(dataFromSpreadSheet); // prints all the number of data
                $(".tableForSpreadsheet").val(dataFromSpreadSheet); // no value is added to value attribute of input tag
              }
            }
          }`  Do you know why this happens??

Comment: Then, I tried another possible solution. But did not work either. `function populateSheet(result){
            for (var row = 0; row < 8; row++){
              for (var col = 0; col < 3; col++){
                var dataFromSpreadSheet = result.values[row][col];
                //console.log(dataFromSpreadSheet);
                $(".tableForSpreadsheet").attr("value", dataFromSpreadSheet); // Only one value is assigned to input value attribute.
              }
            }
          }`

Comment: Actually, I somehow made it work, by adding this piece of code `document.getElementById(row + ':' +col).value = result.values[row][col];` Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your implementation is that `$('.dataFromSpreadsheet').attr('id', row +':'+col);` overwrites the `id` attribute of previously created element.

I would recommend you to create element using [`jQuery(html, attributes)`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes) and use methods i.e. `append()` to add elements to DOM and methods `.css()`, `.val()` to manipulate them.

```js
//Create DIV 
var div = $('<div>')

//Add CSS rule to above created div
div.css("clear", "both")

for (var row = 0; row < 8; row++) {

  for (var col = 0; col < 3; col++) {

    //Create INPUT with attributes
    var input = $('<input>', {
      "class": "dataFromSpreadsheet",
      "type": "text",
      "id": row + ':' + col
    })
    .css("float", "left")
    .val(row + ':' + col);

    //Append It to DIV
    div.append(input);
  }
}

//Append the main div to DOM
$('#container').append(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your answer gave me a better understanding of formatting my code using jQuery. (I have another similar question, so I'd appreciate if you can stop by again! :D)

Comment: Thank you! I failed to assign each data to each value attribute. `function populateSheet(result){
            for (var row = 0; row < 8; row++){
              for (var col = 0; col < 3; col++){
                var dataFromSpreadSheet = result.values[row][col];
                //$(".tableForSpreadsheet").attr("value", dataFromSpreadSheet); //assigns the last data on all value attribute
                //$(".tableForSpreadsheet").val(dataFromSpreadSheet); //assigns no data to value attribute
              }
            }
          }`

Comment: Actually, I somehow made it work, by adding this piece of code document.getElementById(row + ':' +col).value = result.values[row][col]; Thanks for your help :D

Comment: @FluffyCat, Great to know and glad I can help

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  for (var row = 0; row < 8; row++){
    document.write("<div style = 'clear:both'>");
    console.log(row + 'this is row') // this works, starting from 0 to 7
      for (var col = 0; col < 3; col++){
        var id = row +':'+col;
        var newTable = "<input class = 'dataFromSpreadsheet' type = 'text' style = 'float:left' id = "+id+" value = ''>";                
        document.write(newTable);
        console.log(col + 'this is column') // this works, starting from 0 to 2
      }
    document.write("</div>")
  }

  </script>
```